# json to dict, creating multiple rows based on a nested column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a weird problem that I'm not sure how to approach. I basically am calling a json endpoint and I get this:

```
{'Address': 'One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United States, 95014',
 'AddressData': {'City': 'Cupertino',
  'Country': 'United States',
  'State': 'CA',
  'Street': 'One Apple Park Way',
  'ZIP': '95014'},
 'CIK': '0000320193',
 'CUSIP': '037833100',
 'Code': 'AAPL',
 'CountryISO': 'US',
 'CountryName': 'USA',
 'CurrencyCode': 'USD',
 'CurrencyName': 'US Dollar',
 'CurrencySymbol': '$',
 'Description': 'Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets smartphones, personal computers, tablets, wearables, and accessories worldwide. It also sells various related services. The company offers iPhone, a line of smartphones; Mac, a line of personal computers; iPad, a line of multi-purpose tablets; and wearables, home, and accessories comprising AirPods, Apple TV, Apple Watch, Beats products, HomePod, iPod touch, and other Apple-branded and third-party accessories. It also provides AppleCare support services; cloud services store services; and operates various platforms, including the App Store, that allow customers to discover and download applications and digital content, such as books, music, video, games, and podcasts. In addition, the company offers various services, such as Apple Arcade, a game subscription service; Apple Music, which offers users a curated listening experience with on-demand radio stations; Apple News+, a subscription news and magazine service; Apple TV+, which offers exclusive original content; Apple Card, a co-branded credit card; and Apple Pay, a cashless payment service, as well as licenses its intellectual property. The company serves consumers, and small and mid-sized businesses; and the education, enterprise, and government markets. It sells and delivers third-party applications for its products through the App Store. The company also sells its products through its retail and online stores, and direct sales force; and third-party cellular network carriers, wholesalers, retailers, and resellers. Apple Inc. was founded in 1977 and is headquartered in Cupertino, California.',
 'EmployerIdNumber': '94-2404110',
 'Exchange': 'NASDAQ',
 'FiscalYearEnd': 'September',
 'FullTimeEmployees': 147000,
 'GicGroup': 'Technology Hardware & Equipment',
 'GicIndustry': 'Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals',
 'GicSector': 'Information Technology',
 'GicSubIndustry': 'Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals',
 'HomeCategory': 'Domestic',
 'IPODate': '1980-12-12',
 'ISIN': 'US0378331005',
 'Industry': 'Consumer Electronics',
 'InternationalDomestic': 'International/Domestic',
 'IsDelisted': False,
 'Listings': {'0': {'Code': '0R2V', 'Exchange': 'LSE', 'Name': '0R2V'},
  '1': {'Code': 'AAPL', 'Exchange': 'BA', 'Name': 'Apple Inc. CEDEAR'},
  '2': {'Code': 'AAPL34', 'Exchange': 'SA', 'Name': 'Apple Inc'}},
 'LogoURL': '/img/logos/US/aapl.png',
 'Name': 'Apple Inc',
 'Officers': {'0': {'Name': 'Mr. Timothy D. Cook',
   'Title': 'CEO & Director',
   'YearBorn': '1961'},
  '1': {'Name': 'Mr. Luca  Maestri',
   'Title': 'CFO & Sr. VP',
   'YearBorn': '1964'},
  '2': {'Name': 'Mr. Jeffrey E. Williams',
   'Title': 'Chief Operating Officer',
   'YearBorn': '1964'},
  '3': {'Name': 'Ms. Katherine L. Adams',
   'Title': 'Sr. VP, Gen. Counsel & Sec.',
   'YearBorn': '1964'},
  '4': {'Name': "Ms. Deirdre  O'Brien",
   'Title': 'Sr. VP of People & Retail',
   'YearBorn': '1967'},
  '5': {'Name': 'Mr. Chris  Kondo',
   'Title': 'Sr. Director of Corp. Accounting',
   'YearBorn': 'NA'},
  '6': {'Name': 'Mr. James  Wilson',
   'Title': 'Chief Technology Officer',
   'YearBorn': 'NA'},
  '7': {'Name': 'Ms. Mary  Demby',
   'Title': 'Chief Information Officer',
   'YearBorn': 'NA'},
  '8': {'Name': 'Ms. Nancy  Paxton',
   'Title': 'Sr. Director of Investor Relations & Treasury',
   'YearBorn': 'NA'},
  '9': {'Name': 'Mr. Greg  Joswiak',
   'Title': 'Sr. VP of Worldwide Marketing',
   'YearBorn': 'NA'}},
 'Phone': '408-996-1010',
 'Sector': 'Technology',
 'Type': 'Common Stock',
 'UpdatedAt': '2021-02-25',
 'WebURL': 'http://www.apple.com'}
```

you can see it mostly flat except two keys have nested values (address/officers). When I convert it to a dataframe I'm getting :

```
Code    Type    Name    Exchange    CurrencyCode    CurrencyName    CurrencySymbol  CountryName CountryISO  ISIN    CUSIP   CIK EmployerIdNumber    FiscalYearEnd   IPODate InternationalDomestic   Sector  Industry    GicSector   GicGroup    GicIndustry GicSubIndustry  HomeCategory    IsDelisted  Description Address AddressData Listings    Officers    Phone   WebURL  LogoURL FullTimeEmployees   UpdatedAt
Street  AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   One Apple Park Way  NaN NaN 408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
City    AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   Cupertino   NaN NaN 408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
State   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   CA  NaN NaN 408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
Country AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   United States   NaN NaN 408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
ZIP AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   95014   NaN NaN 408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
0   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN {'Code': '0R2V', 'Exchange': 'LSE', 'Name': '0...   {'Name': 'Mr. Timothy D. Cook', 'Title': 'CEO ...   408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
1   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN {'Code': 'AAPL', 'Exchange': 'BA', 'Name': 'Ap...   {'Name': 'Mr. Luca Maestri', 'Title': 'CFO & ...    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
2   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN {'Code': 'AAPL34', 'Exchange': 'SA', 'Name': '...   {'Name': 'Mr. Jeffrey E. Williams', 'Title': '...   408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
3   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Ms. Katherine L. Adams', 'Title': 'S...   408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
4   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Ms. Deirdre O'Brien', 'Title': 'Sr....    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
5   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Mr. Chris Kondo', 'Title': 'Sr. Dir...    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
6   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Mr. James Wilson', 'Title': 'Chief ...    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
7   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Ms. Mary Demby', 'Title': 'Chief In...    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
8   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Ms. Nancy Paxton', 'Title': 'Sr. Di...    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
9   AAPL    Common Stock    Apple Inc   NASDAQ  USD US Dollar   $   USA US  US0378331005    037833100   0000320193  94-2404110  September   1980-12-12  International/Domestic  Technology  Consumer Electronics    Information Technology  Technology Hardware & Equipment Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals  Domestic    False   Apple Inc. designs, manufactures, and markets ...   One Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, United Stat...   NaN NaN {'Name': 'Mr. Greg Joswiak', 'Title': 'Sr. VP...    408-996-1010    http://www.apple.com    /img/logos/US/aapl.png  147000  2021-02-25
```

Basically it looks like each key in the nested keys is creating a new row in the dataframe.  Here's my code:

```
import json 
import requests
import pandas as pd

companyData = requests.get(url="https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX").json()

General =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(companyData['General'])
General
```

In this case, my goal is that everything is just one row and any nesting would just show up as a json in the relevant column. Not create new duplicate rows for every item in the nested json.

Comment: Try `pd.Series(companyData['General'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `pd.json_normalize()` with the `max_level` argument.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(companyData['General'],max_level=0)
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: @piRSquared means a lot coming from you my friend, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it looks awesome. I was confused of where to use json_normalize vs from dict. This is helpful. Thank you!